# Is there an iPhone app that acts as a radio signal strength sensor?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation

I would like to find an iPhone app that is able to show the GSM or WiFi signal strength. Does it exist?

Comment: I don't think that Apple provides any public APIs for interacting with any of the device radios, and would not approve any app that did so with a private API.

Comment: @Jason That is correct - you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple does not provide any public APIs for interacting with any of the device radios, and would not approve any app that did so with a private API.

Comment: Does this still apply? I'm looking for a tool that can monitor/report/assess Bluetooth/WiFi connection status (connected status, strength and possibly any other useful information).